# Count php scripts with certain content with Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to list php block in a mixed html/php script which contains certain information. For example text is:

```
bla bla <?php echo("hello world") ?> <?php

echo($info["xx"])

?> bla and bla

bla bla <?php

echo($info["yy"])

?> bla bla and bla
```

I want to list php blocks which contains "$info" text. Expected result must be:

```
<?php
    
    echo($info["xx"])
    
    ?>
```

and

```
<?php
    
    echo($info["yy"])
    
    ?>
```

I tried `/<\?((.|\n)*)\?>/g` but first of all it doesn't search $info and it returns all the string from first php to the last php block.

Comment: use one flag and increase it in every php block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
'/<\?php\s(?:(?!<\?php\s|\$info).)*?\$info.*?\?>/s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T94eI6/1)

- `<\?php\s` - `<?php` and a whitespace
- `(?:(?!<\?php\s|\$info).)*?` - any char, 0 or more times, that does not start `<?php` + whitespace or `$info` strings
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\?>` - a `?>` substring.